# How can I set the background color of gnome-terminal using gconftool-2?

Tags: gconf

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to set the background color of my gnome-terminal using the command line.
From what I can tell `gconftool-2` is the way to do this but I cant work out what the command is to do this.

my `~/.gconf/apps` directory looks like:

```
├── %gconf.xml
├── gnome-terminal
│   ├── %gconf.xml
│   └── profiles
│       ├── Default
│       │   └── %gconf.xml
│       └── %gconf.xml
└── nm-applet
    └── %gconf.xml
```

If I run

```
gconftool-2 -a /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default
```

I get a long list of key value pairs, e.g. pairs like this

```
scroll_on_output = false
 cursor_blink_mode = system
 background_color = #28F528F528F5
```

which I believe belong to the "default" gnome-terminal profile, but how do I then set these values using `gconftool-2` ?

Ive worked out I can "get" values with

```
gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color
```

but not sure how to assign a new variable, in this case I would guess its a string, e.g. I would expect it to be something like

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color --type=string: #ababab
```

or something like that?

Comment: Why gconftool2 ? you can do that through profile settings in gnome-terminal itself

Comment: its part of a bash install script , dont have access to GUI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently gconftool-2 does not work anymore, however dconf did work for me. Close gnome-terminal and run this in xterm or another terminal emulator, or even tty.

**Step 1**: find the id of your desired profile

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/ | awk '/\[:/||/visible-name=/'
```

My output:

```
[:732eb8b6-054a-446e-b89b-707f3331b62a]
visible-name='G-O'
[:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9]
visible-name='BLACK-GRAY'
[:950cf000-d979-4981-bbdd-65441138c782]
visible-name='B-W'
[:6390ed2d-5768-4650-b4c8-dc1ef4f5da1a]
visible-name='IBM'
[:868caf45-6db6-4427-81f0-d6fa28ef1c3e]
visible-name='gray-green'
[:1960ff5e-ffe6-48c3-8f7c-b771245d62ae]
visible-name='cathode'
[:9176f39d-9b41-4e64-87d9-ea388e3b873d]
visible-name='B-O'
[:98707df3-b227-4a01-ae76-310f8270b9bd]
visible-name='Default'
[:4038ffeb-a484-4c39-aead-9c45f4032f27]
visible-name='PRINT'
[:67607036-706f-4872-bd7d-a3eabf321460]
visible-name='B-G'
```

So my Default profile has id `:98707df3-b227-4a01-ae76-310f8270b9bd`

**Step 2:** allow for using custom colors instead of system colors

`sudo dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:98707df3-b227-4a01-ae76-310f8270b9bd/use-theme-colors "false"`

**Step 3:** set your desired background color

`sudo dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:98707df3-b227-4a01-ae76-310f8270b9bd/background-color "'#ABAB9B9B6060'"`

**Step 4:** (re)start gnome-terminal.

Comment: thanks,when I copy paste your answer, commandline accepts it, `exit status=0` but terminal background doesnt change, If I close and restart terminal, still no change. if I re-reun `gconf --get ....` it returns the previous color . Im suspecting your answer is correct regarding `gconftool-2` but there possibly is a setting or startup script that is overriding the new value?

Comment: @user4668401 strange,  I'm experiencing the same thing. The command is correct, but even with sudo it doesn't work

Comment: dconf works tho

Comment: Interesting , I was suspecting it was because the gnome-terminal inherits its colors from the "system theme" (tickbox option under colors menu) and looking into what the system theme setting is. and Im already overriding the terminal tab colors using CSS so I tried use gtk.css file. no luck. will look into dconf

Comment: @user4668401 I'm gonna edit my post a bit later. I guess it's the thing now in 15.04  . . .go figure, right ?

Comment: hah ,  cool. I'll be interested to see what you discovered when you edit later

Comment: @user4668401 done, czech it out

Comment: nicely done. Unfortunately Im not getting the same result, I should have mentioned but Im on Ubuntu 14.04. I seem to be missing the `dconf /org/gnome/terminal/`  profile. even if I run `dconf dump / ` and search output there is no entry for terminal.

Comment: @user4668401 um . . . well, you could create the schema, I guess, using same command `dconf write`

Comment: oh I didnt of that, I think I forget about supporting 14.04 and use your solution in the script, the script wont set the background for 14.04 , but should be ok for all other versions going forward.

Comment: There's no need for `sudo`, the user can set their own `dconf` settings. Also there's no need to restart gnome-terminal, it should pick up changes immediately.

Comment: Note that the shown commands alter the profile's settings, and as such take effect in _all_ gnome-terminal tabs and windows of this profile. Thus this is a replacement for manually opening the preferences window and picking new colors there. If the user wishes to change the current terminal's color only, without affecting other tabs/windows of gnome-terminal (including newly opened ones), there are escape sequences (e.g. OSC 10 and 11) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that gconf2 does seem to work - had the command wrong.
e.g. this works

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color --type string "#393939"
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 16.04

Comment: @Anwar Shah I think thats because 16.04 has had gtk version increased to 3 from 2 so now use gsettings insread  of gconftool-2