# Edit Gnome-Terminal profile from command line on 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal, dconf, gsettings

I am attempting to edit `Gnome-Terminal` profiles from the command line using `gsettings`. In order to use `gsettings` I need to know the keys and values contained in each profile. My problem is that `dconf-editor` does not display these. I can use `dconf-editor` to view everything down to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles/default`. This displays the UUID for the profile but does not display any of the key/value pairs in the profile. How can I access this information so I can edit a profile using `gsettings`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact `dconf-editor` does show the keys and values of each profile, in the subdirectories of `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/`. Their names are UUID's, with a colon prefix. But the default profile only shows up if it's been modified.

[image: screenshot of dconf-editor]

If you still want to use the command line, `dconf` seems like a better choice, since as far as I can tell, `gsettings` doesn't have access to the individual profile settings, only the default settings for new profiles (not the settings of the default profile). Though on the other hand, `dconf` doesn't seem to have access to the default settings.

#### dconf

Get profiles:

```
dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

Get profiles with their names (from [Sergiy's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/628129/301745)):

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/ | awk '/\[:/||/visible-name=/'
```

List all settings:

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

#### gsettings

Get profiles:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.ProfileList list
```

Get default profile:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.ProfileList default
```

Get settings (I think these are the default settings for new profiles):

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/
```

Comment: On my system, when I select the default profile in dconf-editor I only get a screen which permits me to select whether to use the default UUID or provide a custom UUID. I do not get a screen listing the keys and values for the profile as I do farther up in the hierarchy. Do you mean that there is a way to get such a screen?

Comment: @Jonathan You're selecting the *setting for which profile is default* not the actual default profile itself. Go up a level, look up, and you'll see the profile directories there. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: You are right. I simply did not realize that the top line was active.

Comment: @Jonathan Actually I just tried some things and noticed if you haven't edited the default profile, it doesn't show its subdirectory. That might be part of the confusion.

Comment: Actually I had edited it before trying as I had encountered this proviso.

Comment: I also confirmed that gsettings will not allow you to edit the individual entries in a profile but dconf will.