# gnome terminal: change background color through bashrc

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors

I want to change the color of the terminal display when entering a SSH session. In the .bashrc I have a snip that changes the prompt when logging in via SSH, but I need to change the whole background color.

The background will apply only when I'm logged into a remote host via SSH.

This thread has a good discussion on changing colors of the terminal display.

[Changing colour of text and background of terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal)

For example the following printf lines in a bash script do exactly what I want - change the color of the line responding to the command and all subsequent lines of that terminal session.

However when included in the .bashrc as below,the effect lasts only for the first line of the session.

```
if [[ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]
  then
  : 
else
   PS1="\[\e[01;36m\]$PS1\[\e[00m\]"
   printf '\e[48;5;125m'
   printf '\e[38;5;255m'
fi
```

Where 48 and 38 select foreground and background, the 5 selects the color table to use (in this case ANSI), and nnnm selects the color from the selected color table.

How can I make the change stick through the terminal session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set built-in color scheme for gnome-terminal via CLI in Ubuntu 16?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803230/how-to-set-built-in-color-scheme-for-gnome-terminal-via-cli-in-ubuntu-16)

Comment: @Win that solution doesn't let you set the default colors, so that won't work.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? If it's 14.04, this is a duplicate of [How can I set the background color of gnome-terminal using gconftool-2?](https://askubuntu.com/q/628122/301745) If it's 18.04, it's almost a duplicate of [Edit Gnome-Terminal profile from command line on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1068595/301745)

Comment: @wjandrea I have changed the question. I hope it is more clear.

Comment: @Stephen I posted a comment here before but I had a few details wrong so I removed it. In fact the only detail missing is what version of Ubuntu you're using (on the local machine).

Comment: Check your `$PS1` value - it might reset the colors after a prompt with color. `man bash`

Comment: @wjandrea I have hosts running 19.04, 18.10,18.04,16.04 all MATE. I want this to work on all of them so that any connection between any two will have the same effect. The Mate terminal is a gnome terminal fork I believe. I haven't encountered any differences so far.

Comment: @waltinator Pretty much anything with colorized output will reset the colors when it's done printing. For example try `printf '\e[42m'; pip show; echo hi`

Comment: Look at the `~/.bashrc` files on the remote systems for `PS1` setting. Use a simple `if [[  -z  "$SSH_CLIENT ]] ; then` (`SSH_CLIENT` is set if you logged in via `ssh`)

Comment: You might be able to use an OSC sequence. See [egmont's answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386027/117037). Can't confirm cause I'm not at my machine rn.

Comment: I have added the snip from my .bashrc. Note that the two printf lines when issued from the command line or included in a bash script have a persistent effect. Thank you @waltinator for the much nicer SSH check. All hosts have the same .bashrc for the user.