# How does Gnome terminal palette work?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

What is this color palette in color preferences of the Gnome terminal?

[image: color palette]

Where can i see which color does what. What every color from this palette is responsible for? You can see that there is a color for text, for bold text and for background. But what's with the palette?

Comment: I think you're looking for this info, indirectly: [How to change the output color of echo in Linux - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5947742/4518341)

Comment: Related: [Changing colour of text and background of terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/558280/301745)

Answer (score 1):

"Where can i see which color does what." – Colors don't *do* anything. They are there for the applications to use.

As terminals evolved through the years, they went from monochrome through 8, 16, 256, and nowadays sometimes even 16 million colors they support. Many utilities still only use the “standard” 16 colors (in addition to the “default” of the emulator), they are the ones whose exact color value can be defined here.