# How do I invert the console background and text colors?

Tags: command-line

I have a command line only installation of Ubuntu 18.04.3. It boots to a login screen, I can login and everything works perfectly. Sometimes I plug it into a projector to give a presentation (from the command line). On a projector, the white text on a black background is hard to read.

[image: console with black background]

How can I invert the console so that the text is black and the entire background is white?

Comment: could you please take a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/1186716/248158. I've quoted you and my experience and that of two others differs with what your quote says. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do better than just invert, you can change the colour scheme to whatever you want from the command line.  The following post has a number of answers so its a case of choosing with answer suits you best and if you really want to have black text on a blindingly bright white background, then this post should cover that too :)

[Changing colour of text and background of terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal)

It appears that the above question doesn't contain any answers that demonstrate how to apply your settings permanently.  I did this myself years back and it involves editing your.bashrc file and its a bit complicated in that you can apply your colours, but commands like *ls* use their own colours.  I found an article on the community wiki that demonstrates how to edit the .bashrc file safely and apply your changes permanently.  Note that the article uses *gedit* to edit the file which is not available in text mode and so obviously you will need to use *nano* or your preferred text editor instead:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

Comment: Thanks. I tried `setterm -term linux -back <background_colour> -fore <text_color> -clear` which changes the colour, as expected. But then if I launch byobu to have multiple windows, it reverts back to white on black.

Comment: Apologies I thought that at least one answer in the question I posted the link to, would demonstrate how to apply your colour changes permanently.  So I posted an article from the Ubuntu Community Wiki that demonstrates how to achieve this.  I hope this helps.