# Reason for snap apps (re)installation on 19.10 upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, snap, 19.10

In 19.04 I had removed all of the snap applications, and installed regular code versions of these same applications.

I upgraded to 19.10 and it reinstalled all of the same snap applications! This can be seen as the various /dev/loop[1-8] devices...

```
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/sda7       568G  381G  159G  71% /
 /dev/loop1      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/107
 /dev/loop2       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/359
 /dev/loop3      157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/91
 /dev/loop0       23M   23M     0 100% /snap/snapd/4992
 /dev/loop4       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
 /dev/loop5      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
 /dev/loop6      4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
 /dev/loop7       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1223
 /dev/sda6        11G  6.7G  4.0G  63% /media/username/Shared_Data
 /dev/sda2        96M   74M   23M  77% /boot/efi
 /dev/sdb1       384G   73G  292G  20% /media/username/Timeshift
 /dev/sdb2        57G   98M   57G   1% /media/username/Shared_Data_2
 /dev/loop8       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1265
```

Any idea why Ubuntu insists on (re)installing snap applications? Don't they delay boot times? What makes these snap applications better?

Comment: To the person who down voted my question within the first 35 minutes of its posting, can you please tell me why it was down voted so that I might try to improve my question?

Comment: From what little I have read, snaps are better for the developers since one snap is good for multi versions.  Don't know if they are better for us yet.

Comment: Relevant: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-stop-forcing-snaps-during-upgrade/13212

Comment: I'm seeing three separate questions: Why do snaps get (re-)installed? Do snaps delay boot? How are snaps different from debs? Each seems worthy of a separate thread. I downvoted because each question currently seems opinioned instead of neutral. Happy to revisit.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for coming forward, and for identifying why the down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.10/ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.manifest). It specifies all the snaps and snap-associated packages that would be installed.

```
gir1.2-snapd-1:amd64    1.49-0ubuntu1
gnome-software-plugin-snap      3.30.6-2ubuntu10
libsnapd-glib1:amd64    1.49-0ubuntu1
snapd   2.41+19.10.1
snap:core       stable  7917
snap:core18     stable  1223
snap:gnome-3-28-1804    stable/ubuntu-19.10     71
snap:gnome-calculator   stable/ubuntu-19.10     501
snap:gnome-characters   stable/ubuntu-19.10     317
snap:gnome-logs stable/ubuntu-19.10     81
snap:gtk-common-themes  stable/ubuntu-19.10     1353
```

The fact that you deleted them in 19.04 shouldn't have affected what's installed in 19.10 but that doesn't seem to be the case.

In 19.04, if you run `sudo apt purge snapd`, doing so would remove, in addition to `snapd`, the snaps presently installed on your system. Now, if you run `sudo do-release-upgrade`, neither `snapd` nor any snaps are installed. Two users, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186716/reason-for-snap-apps-reinstallation-on-19-10-upgrade/1186725#comment1983292_1186725), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186716/reason-for-snap-apps-reinstallation-on-19-10-upgrade/1186725#comment1983292_1186725), have verified this. I also checked, in a VM, that the upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 didn't reinstall snaps or `snapd`, if `sudo apt purge snapd` was run before `sudo apt purge snapd`.

Whether this situation will persist if users eventually upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 is unclear.

However, there's a comment over at [discourse.ubuntu.com](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-stop-forcing-snaps-during-upgrade/13212) worth reading. Quoting from there:

> This just sounds like a feature request in the upgrade tool.
>   Essentially if the user has already removed a snap, and installed the
>   deb of the application, then an upgrade happens they get a thing back
>   that they removed.
>
> However, I’m not sure the upgrade tools have the intelligence to know
>   that you previously removed the snap, and don’t want it back. Further,
>   the point of the upgrade tool is to take you to the new release. Those
>   snaps are part of the new release. I have a feeling if you removed
>   firefox from 19.04 and upgraded to 19.10, you’d get firefox back.
>   Which is a similar use case that you’re describing.

That comment indicates that snaps should be reinstalled which isn't what we, who purged `snapd` see.

(I would also point out that before upgrading to 19.10, I purged several fonts I don't need. They too were not re-installed.)

---

Re.

> What makes these snap applications better?

Martin Wimpress is the new Desktop Director of Ubuntu. He talks about the rationale behind snaps in this video: [Future of Ubuntu & Unpacking Snaps with Martin Wimpress | Part 2 | IG Talks ep. 4](https://youtu.be/BLm3HkZ-sMs?t=330).

Comment: I have a VM currently running 19.04. I completely removed snapd and then ran `sudo do-release-upgrade`. [These](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KJWQspWkW5/) are the packages that'll be installed/removed/updated once the upgrade starts. I can't find the reference for snapd although libraries are to be upgraded and one of them **recommends** snapd.

Comment: I haven't tried doing an actual upgrade. That was the list of packages on which some action would be taken once the upgrade starts.

Comment: @Kulfy - I did the upgrade, after removing all snaps and snapd, and they were not reinstalled. Maybe the key is to remove snapd.

Comment: @ajgringo619 very interesting! Perhaps OP will mention if snapd was also removed or not. It would be worth asking via a comment to the question as well.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Makes sense. But there was nothing like snap:gnome-calculator in **install** category.

Comment: @DKBose I don't recall removing snapd (using snap remove), or if I tried, it may not have let me.

Comment: @heynnema, IIRC `sudo apt purge snapd` would get rid of snapd and all the snaps. Some config files in ~/.local may have remained.